# Why backspace key deletes the entire row in JRuby and what can be the fix for it?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I have developed a couple of tools in JRuby. Both the tools prompt for few questions to the user. While answering these questions if the user wants to correct a wrong entry and hits `backspace` key that deletes the entire line (including the question) instead of deleting just one character.

Below is the piece of code that prompts the questions:

```
require highline/import

def prompt
  begin
      input=ask("\t\tEnter user name: ") do |ch|
              ch=true
          end

      input
  rescue => e
       print "Error -"+e
  end

end
```

I was wondering if anyone of you have seen this kind of problem before and what can be the fix for this? Really appreciate your time and help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using #gets for this? If it behaves differently in MRI it might be a bug you should post to thei rissue tracker.

Comment: How are you prompting?

Comment: @three - I am not using `gets`.

Comment: @minitech I am using `highline gem ask` method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't told us enough to help you. You're making us guess how you've written your keyboard input. Don't do that. Instead, read "[ask]", completely, including the links at the bottom, and do what it says.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for directing me to "How to Ask". I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the working piece of the code. I removed `\t` and changed `ch=true` to `ch.readline=true`. Thank for all of your help and guidance.

```
require highline/import

def prompt
    begin
        input=ask("Enter user name: ") do |ch|
              ch.readline=true
            end

        input
     rescue => e
          print "Error -"+e
      end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using highline gem, then when reading the input instead of

```
input=ask("Enter the Input: "){|ch| ch.echo = true}
```

use

```
input=ask("Enter the Input: ") do |ch|
   ch.readline=true
end
```

Source: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4406162

Comment: that worked. But if I use tab i.e., `\t` it does not work. So I removed tab and it worked fine. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad you have that sorted